# Qual a origem e o significado da palavra “sortelha”?

Tags: significado, ortografia, português-europeu

Vi essa palavra em um filme que se passa em Portugal. Pelo que pesquisei existe  uma vila em Portugal com esse nome. O que não entendi foi de onde vem essa palavra e quais são os seus significados.

Qual a origem e o significado da palavra *sortelha*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim existe uma freguesia de [Sortelha](https://www.google.pt/maps/place/Sortelha/) no [Concelho de Sabugal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sortelha) no interior norte de Portugal.

Da minha rápida e superficial investigação, segundo o Priberam [sortelha](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/sortelha) deve derivar de [sortilha](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/sortilha) que aparentemente é um nome para um anel.

> [Antigo]  Anel empregado especialmente em sortilégios ou magia. = SORTELA, SORTELHA, SORTÉLIA
>
> "sortilha", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/sortilha [consultado em 23-07-2016].

Se pesquisar por [sortilha no Google](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&hl=en&lr=lang_en%7Clang_pt&q=sortilha) aparecem inclusive algumas imagens de anéis de joalheiros

Provavelmente existe depois alguma história tradicional ou lenda que associa o nome da terra a alguma situação envolvendo o nome *sortilha* que veio mais tarde a dar origem ao nome da terra, mas isso já desconheço.

Segundo [este artigo](https://autoandrive.com/2010/04/08/aldeia-historica-e-castelo-de-sortelha/) aparentemente o nome era originalmente "Pena de Sortelha" poderá ter a haver com a forma ovalada da muralha do Castelo de Sortelha, que lembra vagamente um anel.

Comment: No conselho de Sabugal?   Não seria no Concelho de Sabugal?

Comment: Certíssimo, corrigido. Obrigado

Comment: @Centaurus Desconhecia a existência da palavra "concelho", achei que o correto fosse sempre "conselho". Após o seu comentário fui pesquisar e descobri que ambas palavras estão corretas, cada uma com seu significado. +1

Comment: @JoãoVictorOliveira   Aqui no Brasil poucos conhecem a palavra "concelho".  Em Portugal é corriqueira.